# How can I store format string in a field and avoid the format-nonliteral warning as well?

Tags: c++, clang, printf

I know you can place `__attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 0)))` to avoid the clang warning of "format string is not a string literal" if a function needs to pass a format string into vsnprintf. However in my case, the format string is saved as a field which is initialized with a literal. Something like this:

```
class Worker {
    const char* format;
    Worker(const char* f): format(f) {...}

    void go() {
        ...
        vsnprintf(..,..,format,..);
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I avoid the warning?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-nonliteral"` or replace `clang` with `GCC`:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;

class Worker {
    const char* format;
    Worker(const char* f): format(f) { }

    void go(int j, ...) {
        char data[256];
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, j);
        #pragma clang diagnostic push
        #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-nonliteral"
        vsnprintf(data, sizeof(data), format, args);
        #pragma clang diagnostic pop
        va_end(args);
        fputs(data, stderr);
    }
};
```

The `push` and `pop` limit the scope of the changes in diagnostic handling so that only the one line is exempted from the warning.  For more information, see [GNU diagnostic pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas) and [Clang diagnostic pragmas](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas).

The code above compiles cleanly with:

```
$ clang -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wformat-nonliteral -c clang.cc
```

It fails noisily with GCC.  Replace the `clang` with `GCC` and it compiles cleanly under both GCC and Clang.

Tested on Mac OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks with:

- GCC (`g++`) 4.8.2
- Clang (`clang`) 'Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)'.